# mysqli::real_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50614 Library:50544

Tags: mysqli, codeigniter-3

codeigniter 3.0.6 gives error 
    mysqli::real_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch.            Headers:50614 Library:50544

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i updated my mysql server or client version, what you have to do is install mysqlnd, you can use

> yum install php54-mysqlnd

it depends on your php version, you can check it using `phpinfo();` or running `php -i` on bash